# Grid inside a panel extJS (Sencha)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was trying to put a grid inside a panel, (I've already done it with 2 different views, I mean, putting the grid in one view and visualizing it from the panel (Menu) view as an Item).

But I need to put it directly on the Menu view and I saw some people doing it with functions to insert it inside the panel but I couldn't do it yet.

If someone can help me I would appreciate it,

Thank you!

**Here is the Menu view**

```
Ext.define('appBaldas.view.vMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    defaultType: 'panel',
    defaults: {
        bodyPadding: 25
    },

    requires: [
        'appBaldas.store.sMenu'
    ],

    items: [{
        title: 'TAB 1',

    }, {
        title: 'TAB 2',

    }, {
        title: 'TAB 3',

    }, {
        title: 'TAB 4',

    }],
/* I SAW SOMETHING LIKE THIS BUT IDK HOW TO IMPLEMENT IT
    _grid : function() {
        this.cellEditing = new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
            clicksToEdit : 1
        });
        return{
    columns: [{ 
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'prodName',
        width: 700,
    }, {
        text: 'Cod',
        dataIndex: 'cod',
        width: 700 
    }, { 
        text: 'Units',
        dataIndex: 'uds',
        width: 700 
    },
    {
        selectable: {
        checkbox: true
    },

    }],
        },
*/
});
```

**Here is the store**

```
Ext.define('appBaldas.store.sMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.sMenu',

    model: 'appBaldas.model.mMenu',

    
    data: { items: [
        { prodName: 'Prod1', cod: "1", uds: "999" },
        { prodName: 'Prod2', cod: "2", uds: "999" },
        { prodName: 'Prod3', cod: "3", uds: "999" },
        { prodName: 'Prod4', cod: "4", uds: "999" }
    ]},

    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
});
```

**Here is the Model**

```
Ext.define('appBaldas.model.mMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
         'prodName', 'cod', 'uds',
    ]
});
```

**I didn't implement the controller yet if necessary**

Answer (score 0):

you have an example while creating a hello world app using Sencha CMD or Open tooling.

A menu view and opens in center. Have you tryed this?